# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my HTML file. When i am running the HTML page it is showing error,'Cannot read property 'split' of undefined'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
            <head>
                <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>

                <script>
                     var appModule=angular.module('appModule',[]);
                     appModule.filter('removeDashes',function(){
                         return function(text){
                             if(text!==undefined){
                                 return text.split('-').join(' ');
                             }
                         }
                     });
                     appModule.controller('someCTRL',function($scope){
                     });
                </script>
             </head>

             <body ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="someCTRL">
            <input type="text" model="someDashedText">
            <p>
                {{someDashedText | removeDashes}}
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: first up!.. change `model="someDashedText"` to `ng-model="someDashedText"`

Comment: did you try console.log(text) before calling the conditional? debugging 101 - use the console

Comment: it should be if(text!=undefined){
                                 return text.split('-').join(' ');
                             }

Comment: Have you tried if `(typeof text != 'undefined')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(text!==undefined){
                             return text.split('-').join(' ');
                         }
```

In my opinion above condition should be replaced with below code

```
if(text){
                             return text.split('-').join(' ');
                         }
```

This condition checks all i.e defined, not null and not empty string.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's good :). If it has solved your problem then please mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `ng` in `<input type="text" model="someDashedText">` => `<input type="text" ng-model="someDashedText">`.

Not sure that 'strict not equal' `!==` operator is necessary here..., you might just check if anything is there `if(text)`

Here is working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1Hplb5N1AnVGA23Wpmm2?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I have made a small code change and created a separate module for the filter and used in the 'appModule'.

You must use "ng-model" in the input.

Here is the working script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
            <head>
                <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script>
                     angular.module('dash',[]).filter('removeDashes',function(){
                         return function(text){
                            if(text!==undefined){
                                 return text.split('-').join(' ');
                             }
                         }
                     });
angular.module('appModule', ['dash']).controller('someCTRL', function($scope){
                     });
                </script>
             </head>

             <body ng-app="appModule" ng-controller="someCTRL">
            <input type="text" ng-model="someDashedText">
            <p>
                {{someDashedText|removeDashes}}
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```